# Retrieving Azure AD Invitation Redemption URL after-the-fact

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

We have a Powershell script that creates some guest users using the New-AzureADMSInvitation cmdlet, and its return value has a handy-dandy InviteRedeemUrl property that we include in a nice welcome email to the user to get them started with setting their account up and using our application.  This works fine when inviting individual or small numbers of users.

However, we'll need to do this for many users, and carefully control when the emails go out, and I can't see any other way of retrieving this URL after-the-fact... the only option seems to be the "Resend invitation" button on the guest user in AD, which sends a Microsoft-branded email from "Microsoft Invitations" with the redeem URL, which is kind of a problem... For marketing reasons we need to put the invite redeem URL in our own welcome email, so we don't want Microsoft sending out those emails.

Is there any way to retrieve or calculate that invitation URL *after* the guest user had already been invited? I know I could delete and recreate the invitation itself, but that's still a manual process and I'd like to be able to create guest users in bulk first, and then retrieve those URLs in bulk once we're ready to send out emails. Especially since Azure AD itself seems to be able to fetch the redeem URLs later on via the "Resend invitation" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up modifying the AD invitation script to store the InviteRedeemUrl value in our CRM as a field on the customer record.  Then later on when our Marketing team wants to start their email campaigns, they could include a reference to this field in the email template just like they would any other field. This way, we got all our analytics on click/open rates and retained complete control over the emails, including where each batch was being sent from (so customers could reply to the correct support staff member for their segment).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively , you can think of adding you company branding in the verification and invitation mails in azure AD.

Here is something similar you can find:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs#how-do-i-customize-verification-emails-the-content-and-the-from-field-sent-by-azure-ad-b2c

[image]

Basically you need to change the company branding in Azure active directory to have your custom logo and text.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, it'll come in handy for the other automatic emails like password resets. However branding is so much more than just the logo and company name - at least for the initial invitation we need to control the whole email, not just these parts, hence the need for retrieving that invite redeem URL